# how to set the limit of minimum and maximum value in Jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script for increment decrements value of a text box, it's working fine. Only thing I need to achieve is, I have to set a minimum and maximum value for it to decrements and increments receptively.

I don't need any alert n message to show the user, I just need it should not change the value after reaching to the limit.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#up").on('click',function(){
    $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())+1);
   });

   $("#down").on('click',function(){
    $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())-1);
   });

 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/93w9d/)**

You can use following. Just set max and min value in `data-max` and `data-min` attribute in `up` and `down` buttons;

```
<input type="button" id="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
<input type="button" id="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
```

And in js;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#up").on('click',function(){
          if ($("#incdec").val() < $(this).data("max")) {
            $("#incdec").val(parseInt($("#incdec").val())+1);
          }
    });

    $("#down").on('click',function(){
          if ($("#incdec").val() > $(this).data("min")) {
            $("#incdec").val(parseInt($("#incdec").val())-1);
          }
    });
});
```

**Edit:** For image buttons : **[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/93w9d/2/)**

**Edit2:** How about if you creating that buttons dynamically more than once?

Let say you have generating buttons dynamically and generate an output like below;

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
    <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
    <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="text" class="incdec" value="0"/>
    <input type="button" class="up" value="Up" data-max="5"/>
    <input type="button" class="down" value="Down" data-min="0"/>
</div>

....
```

And you can use following js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".up").on('click',function(){
          var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
          if ($incdec.val() < $(this).data("max")) {
            $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())+1);
          }
    });

    $(".down").on('click',function(){
          var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");
          if ($incdec.val() > $(this).data("min")) {
            $incdec.val(parseInt($incdec.val())-1);
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of button can i use image for inc dec values? I tried for the same but code stop working

Comment: anyways thanks ..this is the same i'm looking for.. so thanks for helping me !!

Comment: @SaurabhSingh You can see here for image buttons http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/93w9d/2/

Comment: can u tell me how to handle the same for dynamically generated input box. means i can have more than one input box and each one will be associated with two button for increment and decrements its value.

Comment: Thanks for replying..if i have 2 text box then its value is incremented and decremented by 2 on each click. If i have 3 text box then its value is incremented and decremented by 3 and so on. its not incremented and decremented by 1

Comment: yeah..i did the same thing on localhost and its working fine as per my requirement. but on the live website its not working properly. I dont know whats going wrong over there!

Comment: Post your live website link also

Comment: ve u checked on website ?

Comment: Checked, and no up/down button

Comment: u just add 2-3 items in ur cart.. there is up down button on cart page

Comment: Replace `var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");` with `var $incdec = $(this).closest("td").find(".incdec");` and try again

Comment: No.I tried but still its behavior is same as previous. value is not incremented/decremented by 1

Comment: you have no idea about the exact problem ?. on localhost everything is working fine but on live site I dont know why its not working

Comment: But, it is JS. It does depends which server you are. Probably, you did not put some code that exists on your local

Comment: is it something like js conflict or what ? actyally its working but instead of 1,it get incremented/decremented by the number of items in cart

Comment: Could you please replace this `var $incdec = $(this).parent().find(".incdec");` with `var $incdec = $(this).closest("td").find(".incdec");` and try again

Comment: earlier u had suggested to change the same thing and its too not working.U have to notice one thing, for one item in shopping cart its working correct as wee need but as soon as I add more items in cart then only its working in incorrect way. u have cooperated me a lot n I  appreciate for it a lot.

Comment: hey i found the problem why it was not working. Actually I had placed that script at wrong place, that script got repeated again n again whenever we were adding more items.By the way thanks a lot !